# Update `create_at` model attribute only if it is null or blank

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using YII2 advanced application template with yii2-user.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

This will set the current `timestamp` value in my user model. But I want to add this only if it's `null`; it should not be overwritten if I set the value in my controller.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your `TimestampBehavior` with custom logic:

```
<?php
namespace app\behaviors;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\base\Behavior;
use yii\db\Expression;

class ARTimestampBehavior extends Behavior
{

    public function events()
    {
        return [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'beforeInsert',
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'beforeUpdate',
        ];
    }

    public function beforeInsert($event)
    {
        $model = $event->sender;
        if ($model->hasAttribute('created_at') && is_null($model->created_at)) {
            $model->created_at = new Expression('NOW()');
        }
        if ($model->hasAttribute('updated_at')) {
            $model->updated_at = new Expression('NOW()');
        }
    }

    public function beforeUpdate($event)
    {
        $model = $event->sender;
        if ($model->hasAttribute('updated_at')) {
            $model->updated_at = new Expression('NOW()');
        }
    }

}
```

And then use it in your model:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        ARTimestampBehavior::className(),
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try and then let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this.  The closest one can get without much coding it to specify a custom value to be set.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
            'value' => function($event) {
                return (/* some condition */)
                    ? your_custom_function_returning_the_time()
                    : time();
        ],
    ];
 }
```

That being said, I see this as a potential misuse of `TimestampBehavior`.  One might be better off defining a new column for your custom creation timestamp.

If you are set on using the current column, then ditch `TimestampBehavior` and overwrite the `beforeSave` method of your model:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (! parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($insert && this->create_at === null) {
        $this->create_at = time();
    }
    $this->update_at = time();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, in your approach, do I need to modify beforeSave() function in each of my model ?

Comment: Yes, so if you have more than one model for which you need this, I'd say @stepozer's answer is superior to what I was suggesting.

Comment: yes, Thanks for your fast response. I have tried @stepozer's method and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Yii does have built-in support for preserving already filled values from v2.0.13:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::class,
            'preserveNonEmptyValues' => true,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use default TimestampBehavior like this:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * @return array mixed
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'timestamp' => [
            'class' => TimestampBehavior::class,
            'createdAtAttribute' => 'created_at',
            'updatedAtAttribute' => false,
            'value' => function($event) {return $event->sender->created_at ?? new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');},
        ],
    ];
}
```